# Como posso printar esse array de array em forma de tabela

Tags: php, javascript, array

```
  $tabela = array(
    array("Atlético", "Goianiense", "Goiânia", "GO", "0 (não possui)"),
    array("Atlético Mineiro", "Belo Horizonte", "MG", "1 (1971)"),
    array("Atlético Paranaense", "Curitiba", "PR", "1 (2001)"),
    array("Avaí","Florianópolis", "SC", "0 (não possui)"),
    array("Bahia", "Salvador", "BA", "2 (1959, 1988) "),
    array("Botafogo", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "2 (1968[TB], 1995)"),
    array("Chapecoense", "Chapecó", "SC", "0 (não possui)"),
    array("Corinthians", "São Paulo", "SP", "6 (1990, 1998, 1999, 2005, 2011, 2015)"),
    array("Coritiba", "Curitiba", "PR", "1 (1985)"),
    array("Cruzeiro", "Belo Horizonte", "MG", "4 (1966, 2003, 2013, 2014)"),
    array("Flamengo", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "5 (1980, 1982, 1983, 1992, 2009)"),
    array("Fluminense", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "4 (1970, 1984, 2010, 2012)"),
    array("Grêmio", "Porto Alegre", "RS", "2 (1981, 1996)"),
    array("Palmeiras", "São Paulo", "SP", "8 (1960, 1967[RGP], 1969, 1972, 1973, 1993, 1994, 2016) - Não tem MUNDIAL!"),
    array("Ponte Preta", "Campinas", "SP", "0 (não possui) "),
    array("Santos", "Santos", "SP", "8 (1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1968[RGP], 2002, 2004)"),
    array("São Paulo", "São Paulo", "SP", "6 (1977, 1986, 1991, 2006, 2007, 2008)"),
    array("Sport", "Recife", "PE", "1 (1987) "),
    array("Vasco da Gama", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "4 (1974, 1989, 1997, 2000)"),
    array("Vitória", "Salvador", "BA", "0 (não possui)"),


  );
```

---

Estou utilizando um foreach para percorrer o array de array todo, mas não sei printar as linhas divididas em colunas com cada conteúdo, por exemplo: A primeira coluna só deve conter o nome dos times e a segunda a cidade e assim por diante, mas não consigo fazer ele printar no formato desejado.

Comment: Resolvi o problema com esse código, mas não sei se é o mais adequado /     foreach ($tabela as $id => $filter) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$filter[0].'</td><td>'.$filter[1].'</td></td>'.'</td><td>'.$filter[2].'</td>'.'</td><td>'.$filter[1].'</td></tr>';

Comment: Esta tabela não teria as colunas? Qual a origem desses dados?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $tabela = array(
            array("Atlético Goianiense", "Goiânia", "GO", "0 (não possui)"),
            array("Atlético Mineiro", "Belo Horizonte", "MG", "1 (1971)"),
            array("Atlético Paranaense", "Curitiba", "PR", "1 (2001)"),
            array("Avaí","Florianópolis", "SC", "0 (não possui)"),
            array("Bahia", "Salvador", "BA", "2 (1959, 1988) "),
            array("Botafogo", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "2 (1968[TB], 1995)"),
            array("Chapecoense", "Chapecó", "SC", "0 (não possui)"),
            array("Corinthians", "São Paulo", "SP", "6 (1990, 1998, 1999, 2005, 2011, 2015)"),
            array("Coritiba", "Curitiba", "PR", "1 (1985)"),
            array("Cruzeiro", "Belo Horizonte", "MG", "4 (1966, 2003, 2013, 2014)"),
            array("Flamengo", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "5 (1980, 1982, 1983, 1992, 2009)"),
            array("Fluminense", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "4 (1970, 1984, 2010, 2012)"),
            array("Grêmio", "Porto Alegre", "RS", "2 (1981, 1996)"),
            array("Palmeiras", "São Paulo", "SP", "8 (1960, 1967[RGP], 1969, 1972, 1973, 1993, 1994, 2016) - Não tem MUNDIAL!"),
            array("Ponte Preta", "Campinas", "SP", "0 (não possui) "),
            array("Santos", "Santos", "SP", "8 (1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1968[RGP], 2002, 2004)"),
            array("São Paulo", "São Paulo", "SP", "6 (1977, 1986, 1991, 2006, 2007, 2008)"),
            array("Sport", "Recife", "PE", "1 (1987) "),
            array("Vasco da Gama", "Rio de Janeiro", "RJ", "4 (1974, 1989, 1997, 2000)"),
            array("Vitória", "Salvador", "BA", "0 (não possui)"),
          );

          echo "<table  border='1'>";
          for($i=0; $i<count($tabela);$i++){
              echo "<tr>";
              for($j=0; $j<count($tabela[$i]);$j++){
                 echo "<td>".$tabela[$i][$j]."</td>";
              }
              echo "</tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
    ?>
```